# my character is not moving

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, character

I have this code and trying to move my character using jquery inside for loop. If I separate the code, it kind of works, but to me, this code still looks ok. I really don't get why it doesn't move.

```
let currentX = $('character').css('left');
for(i=0; i<100; i++){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.character').css('left',currentX+=3);   //move to right

        if(i>33){
          $('.character').css('left',currentX-=3); //move to left

}else if (i >66){
          if($('.character').css({'background-image':'url(https://gameartpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/03/Golden_Knight_featured.png)'})){
            $('.character').css({'background-image':'url(old-man-game-character.png)'});
          }else{

          $('.character').css('left',currentX+=3);
        }
        }
      },200*i);
  }
```

Comment: let currentX = $('character').css('left'); is missing the (dot).. it should be $('.character') not $('character')

Comment: might be because you missed class specifier dot in `let currentX = $('character').css('left');` its supposed to be $('.character')

Comment: I changed it then tried, but it doesn't work.. aw

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
let currentX = $('character').css('left');
```

to

```
let currentX = $('.character').css('left');
```

You missed the class specifier.